# No mapping exists from object type system.io.memorystream to a known managed provider native type, Windows XP only issue

Tags: c#, sql

Getting Error: System.argumentexception: no mapping exists from object type system.io.memorystream to a known managed provider native type.

My code works fine on Win7-64bit but not on in WinXP-64bit.

The error occurs when the Object being passed in the KeyValuePair is of type Stream or MemoryStream and SQL doesn't know how to handle it.

Here's the code in question:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<frmMain.PARAMS, Object> item in paramDictionary)
{
    sqlCMD.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + item.Key.ToString(), item.Value));
}
```

For reference here's the code making this call:

```
mStream = frmRptViewer.CryRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
Dictionary<PARAMS, Object> pdfDictionary = new Dictionary<PARAMS, Object>();
pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.TYPE, "PDFSAVE");
pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.PDF, mStream);
pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.JOBNUMB, jobNumTextBox.Text);
pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.LINENUMB, lineNumTextBox.Text);
DBCall.SavePDF(pdfDictionary);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it can't handle `Stream` classes. You could try using `byte[]` instead which `MemoryStream` lets you easily do:

```
pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.PDF, mStream.ToArray());
```

You might also want to wrap the stream in a `using() {}` to prevent a leak:

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = frmRptViewer.CryRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)) {
    Dictionary<PARAMS, Object> pdfDictionary = new Dictionary<PARAMS, Object>();

    pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.TYPE, "PDFSAVE");
    pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.PDF, mStream);
    pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.JOBNUMB, jobNumTextBox.Text);
    pdfDictionary.Add(PARAMS.LINENUMB, lineNumTextBox.Text);
    DBCall.SavePDF(pdfDictionary);

}
```

Comment: That did the trick, still wonder why this was an XP machine only issue though.

Comment: @mjrevel Yeh sorry I can't answer you on that one :/